# How to print multiple words in my program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this program that reads a file and prints the desired amount of most common words. I don't know how to print the words that appear the same amount of times.

Here's my code:

```
number_of_words = int(input('Enter how many top words you want to see: '))
uniques = []
stop_words = ["a", "an", "and", "in", "is"]
for word in words:
  check_special = False
  if word.isalnum():
    check_special = True
  if word not in uniques and word not in stop_words and check_special:
    uniques.append(word)

counts = []
for unique in uniques:
  count = 0
  for word in words:
    if word == unique:
      count += 1
  counts.append((count, unique))

counts.sort()
counts.reverse()

for i in range(min(number_of_words, len(counts))):
  count, word = counts[i]
  print('The following words appeared %d each: %s ' % (count, word))
```

As a demo it prints:

```
The following words appeared 11 each: night 
The following words appeared 11 each: go
```

I want the output to be:

```
The following words appeared 11 each: go, night
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can simplify it by just using *collections* *Counter* here.  Then find the max_count from *most_common(n)*.

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve by using this.

```
count_with_word = {}
for i in range(min(number_of_words, len(counts))):
    count, word = counts[i]
    if count in count_with_word:
        count_with_word[count].append(word)
    else:
        count_with_word[count] = [word]

for count, words in count_with_word.items():
    print('The following words appeared %d each: %s ' % (count, ', '.join(words)))
```

Output would be like:
`The following words appeared 2 each: t1, t2`

Answer (score 0):

Use `dict`

```
counts_dict = {count: [] for count, word in counts}
for count, word in counts:
    counts_dict[count].append(word)

count_num_word = 0
for count in counts_dict:
    if count_num_word >= number_of_words:
        break
    print('The following words appeared %d each: %s ' % (count, ', '.join(counts_dict[count])))
    count_num_word += len(counts_dict[count])
```

e.g.

```
words = ['B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C']

> Enter how many top words you want to see: 3
> The following words appeared 2 each: B, A 
> The following words appeared 1 each: C 

> Enter how many top words you want to see: 2
> The following words appeared 2 each: B, A 

> Enter how many top words you want to see: 1
> The following words appeared 2 each: B, A
```

Although you input `number_of_words` as 1, it should return all words that share the same count, as shown in the example.